# How to display a textview 2nd layout I used OnItemClickListener()?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've created a new .xml file in my layout folder called xmls.xml. It contains 1 TextView. I put my getter and setter in ItemDetails.java with properties of imageNumber, name, itemDescription, and price. I have no idea how to display the name, itemDescription, and price in another .xml file. When I click the list in the listView it will automatically display to another .xml file which is xmls.xml.

> ```
> //ListViewImagesActivity.java
> ```

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(ListViewImagesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                }  
            });
        }
```

> //SecondActivity.java

```
  String name = "";
        TextView foodName;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.xmls);

            try {
                foodName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                // Get position to display
                Intent i = getIntent();

                this.name = i.getStringExtra("name");

                foodName.setText(name);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
            }

        }
```

[image: this is the image]

Comment: tell me if I am right.You have a textview(name) in a listview , when you click on any item you want that name to be shown in the next activity also?

Comment: No only listview in another xml file I put one textView. If I click the listview it will change the textView depends on the name of the list for example burger.

Comment: I'm sorry I still dont get it:(

Comment: I add an image above so you will get it sorry for my grammar

Comment: you need to startActivity() using the intent you are passing values with.

Comment: what should happen when you click on an item in the listview?

Comment: you can put the values in intent.

Comment: I want to display the Name, Item Description and price to my xmls.xml or to another .xml layout how can I do that?

Comment: look for examples of `intent`. heres a link [https://www.javatpoint.com/android-explicit-intent-example]